# I am getting an IllegalArgumentException in Hibernate One to One Mapping Project

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am new to hibernate and learning Mappings of hibernate, I have created a Demo code of One to One hibernate mapping, I have defined everything correctly as per my understanding, but I am getting an "IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of", I have defined Mapping correctly in hbm file, My POJO classes are perfectly having getters and setters, but I am not getting any clue about what I am doing wrong, It would be great if someone can answer my question.

This is My Pojo class for which has int idCompany variable because of this i am getting error message as "IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.dto.Company.idCompany".

```
public class Company {

    int idCompany;
    String name;
    String initials;
    String email;
    int contact;
    private Address add;

    public Address getAdd() {
        return this.add;
    }

    public void setAdd(Address add) {
        this.add = add;
    }

    public int getIdCompany() {
        return idCompany;
    }

    public void setIdCompany(int idCompany) {
        this.idCompany = idCompany;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getInitials() {
        return initials;
    }

    public void setInitials(String initials) {
        this.initials = initials;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(int contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

}
```

Here is my Company's hbm file

```
<class name="com.dto.Company" table="company">
<id name="idCompany" column="idCompany">
<generator class="assigned">
<param name="property">add</param>
</generator>
</id>
<property name="name" column="name"></property>
<property name="initials" column="initials"></property>
<property name="email" column="email"></property>
<property name="contact" column="contact"></property>
<one-to-one name="add" class="com.dto.Company" cascade="all" ></one-to-one>
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am saving an object like this-

```
        address.setCountry("India");
        address.setDistrict("Barwani");
        address.setLine1("One Line");
        address.setLine2("Second Line");
        address.setPin(1234);
        address.setState("MP");

        company.setIdCompany(201);
        company.setContact(984545454);
        company.setEmail("ab@mail.com");
        company.setInitials("AB");
        company.setName("Amit");
        company.setAdd(address);

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(company);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
```

Please describe to me why I am getting this issue so I will learn it and never let this issue happen again.
Thank You. :)

Comment: "*`<one-to-one name="add" class="com.dto.Company" cascade="all" ></one-to-one>`*" - the field `add` is not of type `com.dto.Company` ;)

Comment: **Thank You** @Turing85, It is working. I just missed it.

Comment: No problem. There is btw no shame in answering your own question.